# Is an oozie workflow job id unique?

Tags: java, oozie

Is a workflow job id unique within a single oozie server/oozie DB instance?
If we dropped and recreated an external oozie DB or restart oozie server, would new oozie wf ids be unique to previously generated?

We use oozie rest api from our app and register wf ids in our own db to track their status and communication between the app and running oozie wfs, I wonder can I rely on their uniqueness.

Comment: You're more likely to get answers if you add the language in which you're programming in and maybe some code examples.

Comment: @StijnBernards We use Java, but it has nothing to do with languages, I'll try  adding Java tag though.

Comment: Ah sorry for that, but adding a language tag is always a smart thing to do since you'll pop up in the more visited tags :) if it's sorta relevant.

Comment: Well, yeah, that makes sense, considering how hard to get a good answer here when you ask a question yourself, I think half of my questions left unanswered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The oozie workflow ids are composed of `<a 7-digit number>-<server start timestamp>-oozie-<4 character of user name>-<W\C\B>` for example : `0000013-160129104602393-oozie-oozi-W`.

I guess you can decide now, whether you should consider this as unique or not.